# MVC 4 Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Please help, can anyone tell me why my custom validation not firing in my mvc 4 project.

Here's my model...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Old Password is required field.")]
[VerifyOldPassword(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Old Password.")]
public string PasswordOld { get; set; }
```

Attribute Class

```
public class VerifyOldPasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public VerifyOldPasswordAttribute()
    {

    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        string currentValue = value as string;
        string referrenceValue = mtdGetOldPassword(); 

        if (currentValue != referrenceValue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Views :

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PasswordOld, new { @class = "txtInputLong" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordOld, "", 
             new { style = "font-family:Arial;font-size:small;font-weight:bold;color:red" })
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: Just copied your code into my project and it works fine (or are you expecting client side validation as well?)

Comment: The custom validation you created just works only on the server side but not on the client side since it does not implement IClientValidatable. Check whether you ModelState.IsValid property is false when the valid data is not provided.

Comment: @Venkat, I suspect from OP's code that client side validation wont work here because its getting the old value from somewhere (database)? so either the built-in [RemoteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) or  [CompareAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be a better solution for client side validation

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke I totally agree your point that better to use RemoteAttribute for checking the value from database. Or else to alter his validation attribute to derive from the CompareAttribute to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

please check if these setting correct or not in your project's web.config?

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: are you getting any error? javascript or jquery error?